# A special random subset of uniformly distributed numbers is still uniformly distributed?

Tags: probability

Assume that I have a value range [1,1000].

Goal: I want to have 10 numbers randomly sampled from [1,1000].

case1:

```
I sample 20 numbers, a1, ..., a20 from [1,1000].

Then I sample b1, ..., b10 from [a1, a2, ..., a20].

b1, ..., b10 are what I want.
```

case2:

```
I partition [1,1000] into 10 intervals, 

I1=[1,100], I2=[101,200], ... I10=[901,1000].

Then I sample one number bi from Ii. 

Eventually I still have 10 numbers b1, ..., b10.
```

I know that case2 is not equivalent to case1, because the sampled numbers in case1 are uniformly distributed.

But can I say "in some sense, the sampled numbers are approximately uniformly distributed?"

Comment: Case 1: They are still uniformly distributed. The order doesn't matter. Case 2 isn't true, since you can never get the set $\{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1\} $.

Comment: Case 2 is very far from simple random sampling. In the layman's sense, numbers chosen in Case 1 will often feel less uniformly spread than numbers chosen in Case 2. However, numbers in Case 2 have a very far from uniform distribution. There may be good reason for such stratified sampling, but close to uniform distribution it isn't.

Comment: @CalvinLin If I always do the sampling without replacement, then the set {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1} will not happen. Under this circumstance, seem to be better?

Comment: If I have two sets of observations (sampled numbers), how can I test their distributions are close to each other? seem that kolmogorov smirnov test can do this job? if so, then I can sample 10 numbers in case1 and 10 numbers in case2. And then, use KS test to know whether they are "close" to each other or to know how far away from each other

Comment: @user4778 Even if you do it without replacement, the second case cannot give you $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 \}$. Because getting a 1 means you can never get another number in the range 1-10.